# SequenceInformation missing

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm working with a Spring boot Application connecting to an AS400 Database using the com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver driver with Spring Data JPA.
I use the org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect dialect.
When I start the Application, I get the Error

```
Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSCAT.SEQUENCES;TABLE, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

Meaning the Table `SYSCAT.SEQUENCES` is missing, which it is, because it's not needed.
The Application works fine, but the error bothers me.
As far as I see, SequenceInformations are only important when I generate an ID somewhere, what I don't do.
This Application is only used to copy data from one place to another, so I only use JPAs `@Id` annotation but not the `@GeneratedValue` one.
Am I missing some use for the SequenceInformation?
Is there some way to turn off the fetching of SequenceInformation?

Those are my application properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    hikari.connection-test-query: values 1
    hikari.maximum-pool-size: 25
  jpa:
    database-platform: DB2Platform
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dll-auto: none
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this question, i had the same problem and same scenario, i sugges to change the title of question to "sequence information cannot be fetched frim DB2" and thanks again

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You use the wrong dialect. Please use:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
```

Comment: Could you please point to any documentation for this. Not sure why every post and documentation suggests using org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect

Comment: Man!! I have been searching for this since last 4 hours. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Thanks, i had the same problem and i found this response is very useful

Comment: yes but now there is a warning "DB2AS400Diealect is deprecated, use DB2Dialect instead" but using DB2Dialect  there is an error "SEQUENCES in SYSCAT of type *FILE not found"...

Answer (score 3):

I have changed dialect from DB2Dialect to DB2400Dialect and it worked for me.

```
##spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
```